# Crash at the AppDelegate (top_level_code) when button is pressed in a popup

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have found [this example app](https://github.com/psy2k/NMPopUpView), which works great. Now I copied the files `PopUpViewController_iPad.xib` and `PopUpViewControllerSwift.swift` to my project to use it. But on my project is crashes when I tap the 'close' button. The green exception line shows me the `AppDelegate` class declaration line (the error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS). The command line area shows me only the `lldb` command and no error message. I know I can query the `lldb` for information, but I don't know how to work with `lldb`.

The error:

[image]

The stack trace:

[image]

Since I run it for iPad air, I put in my projects main view controller the following three lines (which I copied from the example app)

```
popViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift(nibName: "PopUpViewController_iPad", bundle: nil)
popViewController.title = "This is a popup view"
popViewController.showInView(self.view, withImage: UIImage(named: "typpzDemo"), withMessage: "You just triggered a great popup window", animated: true)
```

I thought it may be simply sending the `touchUpInside` message the the parent view which showed this popup, so I just implemented there another `closePopup` method with a simple `println("1")`, but nothing changed.

I also tried adding to `PopUpViewControllerSwift.swift` the line `self.closeButton.becomeFirstResponder()` inside the `viewDidAppear` method (of course with a defined outlet). But the bug remained the same.

I have checked that the identity inspector of "File's owner" and the Class is set correctly to PopUpViewControllerSwift, the module is None (just like in the example). I checked all outlets and stuff, but could not find any difference.

Anyone knows whats up?

Comment: Check in your Thread 1 for a breakpoint which shows some more informations. (check queue-element 1-14)

Comment: It crashes in sendAction. So probably some target going into the wild.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz What should I see in element 1-14? It's assembly code.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Any ideas on how to find out which one?

Comment: I mean the names. For example at 1 there is `sendAction` visible. Often the queue titles show some hints.

Comment: I'm no IOS developer, but in OSX you can add a breakpoint for all exceptions. There should be also a log message telling which one is offending.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz Well obviously, as I said this happens when I press the button. But how can I find out where the action is going and how to change that?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I have already set that global breakpoint. No change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's simply looking in the wrong file for the implementation, but no idea why and how to change that.

Comment: The log entry look e.g. like `2015-01-28 15:24:23.026 temp[6212:65838] -[temp.AppDelegate none:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000033180` here it's `none:` which is missing

Comment: I wish... But as I said, I get only the `lldb`. No error message.

Comment: Just a dumb question: you have turned on debugging?

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yes, I just checked with a breakpoint at the showAnimate function.

Comment: Did you check all outlets?

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like you already checked outlets, to help future readers with a similar problem, if using Storyboard, this often occurs because an outlet is missing. Be sure to check all view controllers, not just the initial view controller, for missing outlets.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different error but still the same symptom - reason? I had forgotten to include some used fonts to the new target :-/